# Automate data substitution in a data frame

Tags: r

I am reading a tab-separated .txt file with two fields of data (V1 and V2) into RStudio using `read.table`

```
    V1      V2
    Ndepmax 3000
    intx    6
    Sdepmax 3000
    inty    6
```

This .txt file contains a list of parameter values that will be used as input to an .exe that will be run from RStudio using the `system()` command available in base R

I would like to iterate running this .exe with different values for `Ndepmax`

I am planning to pull the values for `Ndepmax` from another data table by looping through a list of `spec_num` values and using the `vlookup` command from the `expss` package

```
maxNdep <- vlookup(spec_num, MinMaxNdep, result_column='NDEP30_max')
```

I have not been able to determine how to take these iterative values of `maxNdep` and use them to replace the value for `Ndepmax` in the input file that will be passed to the .exe using `system()`

Any advice for how to accomplish this substitution would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: Further code/clarification is included below...

```
# Input parameter file to use for building the string for "clf_cmd"
in_file = read.table("input.txt")
head(in_file, 4)
       V1   V2
1 Ndepmax 3000
2    intx    6
3 Sdepmax 3000
4    inty    6

# File containing min/max Ndep
MinMaxNdep = read.table(MinMaxNdep, header = TRUE)
head (MinMaxNdep, 1)
  SPNUM NDEP30_min NDEP30_max
1 33786    12.7265    22.7265

# Identify species of interest
# I will ultimately loop through a set of spec_num values, but just starting with a single species for now
spec_num <- MinMaxNdep$SPNUM[1]

# Define maxNdep value to use for substitution into `in_file`
library(expss)
maxNdep <- vlookup(spec_num, MinMaxNdep, result_column='NDEP30_max')

# Substitute value of maxNdep for the value of Ndepmax included in the `in_file` data frame
# Not sure how to do this???
# Need to replace the value of 3000 for Ndepmax in the `in_file` data frame with the maxNdep value included in `MinMaxNdep` for spec_num = 33786

# string passed to cmd line for running the .exe
clf <- system((paste0("clf i:in_file", spec_num, ".in"))
```

Comment: It is note exactly clear what you want. Please make a minimal reproducible example: share impute files, show your R code running with those files and describe more clearly what the problem is.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do so, but it may take me a bit. In the meantime, it would be great it anyone can decipher and provide guidance.

Comment: I essentially need to iteratively replace the current value of 3000 for `Ndepmax` with values from another data table (named `MinMaxNdep`)...working on better describing my code/question...

Comment: Question has been edited to further clarify